# Meteor 0.9.1.1: Issue executing two synchronous Meteor methods

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to sort out an issue where I want two synchronous functions executed.  I have both working in isolation but not one after the other.

I call the Meteor.method called "createImage" and this calls another method on the server called "writeImage".  Once the file has been written I want it to then write the CSS in the "writeCss" function call.

The problem is the "writeCss" call isn't being invoked.

Can anyone suggest a way to sort this?  I was trying to clean my code up a little and prevent my spinner from terminating prematurely.

```
Meteor.call('createImage', params, function(err, result){
            if (!err) {
              // remove the overlay on success
              LoadingOverlay.destroyLoadingOverlay(selector);
             }
           });

createImage: function(params) {
  console.log('write image');
  Meteor.call('writeImage', params);
  console.log('written image');

  /* execution stops here */

  console.log('write css')
  Meteor.call('writeCss', params);
  console.log('written css')

  console.log('image and css written')
  return true;
},


writeImage: function(){
  writeImageAsync = function(gm, source, params, publicRoot){
  console.log('in writeImageAsync')
  var im = gm.subClass({imageMagick: true});
  im(source)
  .crop(params.a, params.b, params.c, params.d)
  .write(publicRoot + 'myimage.png', function(err){
    if (err) return console.dir(arguments)
       console.log('image has been written')
       /*
        This is as far as it gets.  Doesn't return from here
       */ 
    })
  };

writeImageSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(writeImageAsync);
writeImageSync(gm, source, params, publicRoot);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Meteor._wrapAsync`, the wrapped function is called with an additional callback argument. You have to call that callback when you're finished. The callback follows the node.js convention - its first argument is the error, or null if there wasn't an error; the second argument is the return value, if there is one.

```js
// you probably didn't mean to make a global here
writeImageAsync = function(gm, source, params, publicRoot, callback){
  console.log('in writeImageAsync')
  var im = gm.subClass({imageMagick: true});
  im(source)
  .crop(params.a, params.b, params.c, params.d)
  .write(publicRoot + 'myimage.png', function(err){
    if (err) {
      console.dir(arguments);
      callback(new Error("error writing image"));
    } else {
      console.log('image has been written');
      callback(null);
    }
  });
};

writeImageSync = Meteor._wrapAsync(writeImageAsync);
writeImageSync(gm, source, params, publicRoot);
```

Comment: That sorted it thank you and yes I didn't mean to make a global there :)